# How to set marginLeft property in a JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, margin

I have the following code, and I need the calender icon to leave a margin of about 156px in the left.. How should i add this styling?

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "../static/datepicker/images/calender-icon.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Have a look at the HTML generated by `.datepicker()` and add style rules for the classes accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using [this plugin](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/), it comes with a `datePicker.css` where you can simply edit `a.dp-choose-date` (thats the icon) and add `margin-left`.

for the [datepicker coming with jqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), the style you should edit is `ui-datepicker-trigger`.

Answer (score 1):

You can look on the theming section of the control in the jQuery documentation which will describe the CSS classes used for different parts of the control.

With these, as Felix touched on, you can apply the style through your CSS by overriding the default styling for the class.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#theming

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose this Calendar, inside an Div and for that DIV you can do.

```
$(div).css('marginLeft',156);
```

Answer (score 0):

It creates `ui-datepicker-trigger` class on the calander image and you can use css property on this class in your css and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `.css("margin-left","156px")`